# Unable to access Ssl error list from QNetworkAccessManager reloaded

Tags: qt, ssl, qtnetwork

I have a problem with the usage of the QList object.

I think, it's not the same problem as in [Unable to access Ssl error list from QNetworkAccessManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004391/unable-to-access-ssl-error-list-from-qnetworkaccessmanager)

I created a project using QSslSocket and now I want to switch over to the QNetworkAccessManager. But as soon I insert the following line in my header file

```
private slots:
    void _sslErrors(QList<QSslError> errors);
```

I get the following linker error

```
c:\qt\4.4.3\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/global/qglobal.h(1711) : error C2027: use of undefined type 'QSslError'
        c:\qt\4.4.3\include\qtnetwork\../../src/network/access/qnetworkaccessmanager.h(58) : see declaration of 'QSslError'
        c:\qt\4.4.3\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qlist.h(347) : see reference to class template instantiation 'QTypeInfo<T>' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=QSslError
        ]
        c:\qt\4.4.3\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qlist.h(346) : while compiling class template member function 'void QList<T>::node_copy(QList<T>::Node *,QList<T>::Node *,QList<T>::Node *)'
        with
        [
            T=QSslError
        ]
        c:\qt\4.4.3\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qlist.h(524) : while compiling class template member function 'QList<T>::~QList(void)'
        with
        [
            T=QSslError
        ]
        tmp\moc_QFastdmuHttpBatchClientModuleSSLRepositoryIndex3.cpp(72) : see reference to class template instantiation 'QList<T>' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=QSslError
        ]
c:\qt\4.4.3\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qlist.h(349) : error C2514: 'QSslError' : class has no constructors
        c:\qt\4.4.3\include\qtnetwork\../../src/network/access/qnetworkaccessmanager.h(58) : see declaration of 'QSslError'
```

I know, this should only happens, if the openssl support is deactivated, but I compiled Qt with active openssl, QSslSocket::supportSsl() returns true and I had already connected successfully to a SSL server with the pure QSslSocket object.

Btw: As soon I include the QNetwork/QSslSocket to the header file, the compiler doesn't break.

Has someone an idea what goes wrong ?

Thx,
Robert

Comment: Looks like a compiler, not a linker error, to me. Did you include <QSslError>?

Comment: Can you please make an answer out of this ? Then I mark it the correct answer.

Comment: As additional info:

Unlike the QSslSocket class, the QNetworkAccessManager class doesn't include the QSSlError header file, so it has to bew include it excplicit.